# Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable

I am getting an error when I try to parse the `volumeInfo`. I am able to retrieve `totalItems`, `id` and `etag` if I omit `var volumeInfo: [VolumeInfo]?` in `Items` struct, but when I add `var volumeInfo: [VolumeInfo]?` in `Items` struct, the parsing is not happening and I am getting the above error.

This is my JSON response data:

```
{
    "kind": "books#volumes",
    "totalItems": 2361,
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "books#volume",
            "id": "_eyJAAAAQBAJ",
            "etag": "MJbx6HKC3B4",
            "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/_eyJAAAAQBAJ",
            "volumeInfo": {
                "title": "A Quilting Life",
                "subtitle": "Creating a Handmade Home",
                "authors": [
                    "Sherri McConnell"
                ],
                "publisher": "C&T Publishing Inc",
                "publishedDate": "2013-02-12",
                "description": "Bring the handmade tradition home with these charming quilts and home accessories. Inspired by a grandmother who loved to sew for her family, quilter and blogger Sherri McConnell gives traditional patterns like hexagons, stars, snowballs, and Dresden Plates a new look featuring fabrics by some of today’s most popular designers. 19 cozy projects include pillows, tote bags, table runners, and larger quilts—quick and easy designs that make great gifts.",
```

Data model:

```swift
struct Book: Codable {
    var totalItems:Int = 0
    var items:[Items]?
}

struct Items: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var etag: String?
    var volumeInfo: [VolumeInfo]?
}

struct VolumeInfo: Codable {
    var authors: String?
    var categories: String?
    var description: String
    var pageCount: Int?
    var publishedDate: String?
    var publisher: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var title: String?
}

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=quilting"
    var items: [Items] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        guard url != nil else {
            return
        }

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { [self] (data, response, error) in
            //check for errors
            if error == nil && data != nil{

                //parse json
                let decorder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let bookInfo = try decorder.decode(Book.self, from: data!)
                    items = bookInfo.items!
                    print("Retrieved books are \(items)")
                }
                catch {
                    print("Error in json parcing\(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        //make api call
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: `var volumeInfo: [VolumeInfo]?` should be `var volumeInfo: VolumeInfo?` -- it's not an Array, it's a Dictionary

Comment: Looks like volumeInfo->authors is incorrect too... you've got it as a string, but it's an array in the JSON.